# How to create a service task in JBPM

Tags: jbpm, business-process-management, drools-guvnor

I'm able to integrate drools with designer .Now I want to create a custom service component .
I really appreciate if any one tell me the process of creating custom component .

PS  :I'm newbie in JBPM so kindly tell me in easy manner :-)

Answer (score 0):

Which designer are you using, I assume the web-based jBPM designer?
See http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v5.4/userguide/ch.designer.html#d0e4355

Comment: web based designer itself.but I don't know how to create a custom component like this http://people.redhat.com/kverlaen/twitter-repository.swf